# How do I move an HTML element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

My HTML structure is like this:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="1">Some content</div>
   <div id="2">Some content</div>
</div>
```

I want to move the element `id="2"` to place before `id="1"` so its will be like this:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="2">Some content</div>
   <div id="1">Some content</div>
</div>
```

How do I do something like that in jQuery?

Comment: @rahul - they're invalid *in HTML4*, be clear about that given the changes lately ;)

Comment: @rahul: ID is just only for example :), the real script of course not that.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/), like this:

```
$("#2").insertBefore("#1");
```

Or, [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/), like this:

```
$("#2").prependTo("#parent");
```

...or the reverse using `#1` and [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) and [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)...or several other ways actually, it just depends what you're actually after, the above 2 methods should be about the shortest possible though, given 2 IDs.

I'm *assuming* this is just an example, remember to use IDs that don't start with a number in an actual HTML4 page, they're invalid and cause several issues.

Comment: thank you for understand if ID just only for example, and also your code `$("#2").insertBefore("#1");` is clearing my problem... thank you very much :)

Answer (score 8):

Simply do:

```
$('#1').before($('#2'));
```

Comment: why the     `$('#2')  `      instead of just   `'#2'`   ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales Because, the [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method expects, as parameter, an HTML string or a DOM element or an array of elements or a jQuery object. `'#2'` is not any of those.

Answer (score 3):

Ever thought about using [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) ?