# Position div relative to non-parent div - is this possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to position a `div` relative to another `div` which is not it's parent? For example:

```
<div id="header"><!-- --></div>
<div id="content"><!-- --></div>
<div id="footer"><<!-- --></div>
```

In the above code, could `#footer` be relatively positioned to `#header`?

**UPDATE**

I ask because the semantic structure of the design I intend to implement doesn't match the way I want to present it. Visually I'll have a menu at the top of the page and a hidden div which will slide in above the menu on a click event. I therefore need to shuffle the order or divs such that a `#menu` is relatively positioned below a `#header` and will stay relatively positioned when the `#header` slides in on a jQuery `slideToggle()` event.

```
<div id="menu"><!-- --></div>
<div id="header"><!-- --></div>
<div id="content"><!-- --></div>
<div id="footer"><<!-- --></div>
```

`#header` should be fixed to the top of the window. `#menu` should be positioned relative to `#header` such that when `#header` slides in, `#menu` slides down by the same distance.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: actually when we add div's so its come automatically relative by each other so if want to move the div's up & down without touching our markup so we can use the positioning but here we didn't understand your exact requirement so can you post a image of your desired result.......

Comment: Updated with more details on the problem.

Comment: @Graeme got it your point please post your css as well as.....want to see how did u try....

Comment: @ShaienderArora I haven't implemented yet, currently just trying to work out if it's possible as I have no idea how it would be. I don't see how you can name an element in jQuery to position relative against. It looks like it assumes positioning relative to parent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Move an Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428312/jquery-move-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I move an HTML element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428312/jquery-move-an-element)

This question provided the answer I required. Basically you can use jQuery to move the element  in the DOM on page load; note it's important to allow the page to load first before attempting to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You haven't said how you want them positioned, but you can get the current position of `#header` using [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) like this:

```
var pos = $("#header").offset();
```

...and you can set the position of `#footer` as desired via either `css`:

```
$("#footer").css({
    position: "absolute",
    left:     /* some value here*/,
    top:      /* some value here*/
});
```

...or via [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2):

```
$("#footer").offset({
    left:     /* some value here*/,
    top:      /* some value here*/
});
```

...where (in either case) you fill in the left and top values you want, based on the position of the header.

`offset` accepts numbers for `left` and `top`. [Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023618/archer) tells us in the comments that `css` does as well and adds `"px"` for us, and that does seem to work, although I'm not seeing it in the documentation, so I've always put the "px" on myself.

Comment: I also suggest to set `#footer` position using `.offset({})`

Comment: @Archer: Does jQuery add them when you call `css`?

Comment: @Archer: I did, I just wasn't 100% sure it wasn't Chrome being really smart. :-)

Comment: Which it does tend to be! :p

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, made an update which may clarify the problem a little.

Comment: Marking as possible duplicate, answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428312/jquery-move-an-element. Simply re-arrange the elements and position the elements on page load and position them relatively on the assumption they've been re-arranged.