# CSS Position from non-parent element

Tags: css, xhtml

I have a coding restriction that I cannot change and trying to find a way around it, to position a div based on a non parent.

I have the following code structure, which cannot be changed:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="sub-row01"></div>
   <div class="sub-row02"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div id="sub-row03"></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is position #sub-row03 in relation to .sub-row02. Anything that I have tried, will only allow me to position #sub-row03 in relation to first .row

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible? If so, what would be the proper way to style it?

Comment: What html is in the divs? The html looks improperly formatted.

Comment: This is how a Wordpress theme is generating the code via shortcodes. What part of the above code you think is improperly formatted?

Comment: *semantically the code does not look well formatted. But I guess it doesn't matter if you can't change the html format... either way CSS does not allow you to move up the document tree. So you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question it is not possible with pure css since it only allows styling using the parent or a preceding child.

For example

```
a + b { } will style b
a ~ b { } will style b
a > be {} will style b
```

but there is no way to style a in these cases.

You can however do this via javascript.  If you want to go this route you could do something like:

```
document.getElementById("sub-row03").style.left = document.getElementById("sub-row02").offset().left;
```

I can write something a bit more concrete if necessary as I have not tested it but it should help with the basic concept.

Comment: It will be amazed to see if the question can be resolved in pure css. But I agree this answer. User javascript or jQuery to locate selector and then update css. This previous answer may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762616/position-div-relative-to-non-parent-div-is-this-possible