# location by id js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make, that by pressing "a" in the "div" the opening window should be between "div".

Pressed "id 2", the window was displayed between "id 1" and "id 3". Pressed "id 3", the window displayed between "id 2" and "id 4".

```js
 $('#add').hide();
 
 $('#open_add').click(function() {
        $('#add').show(); 
        $('#3').hide();
     });
     
 $('#close_add').click(function() {
        $('#add').hide();    
        $('#3').show();
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add">
<a href="#" id="close_add">Close add</a>
</div>

<div id="1">
  <p>First</p>
</div>

<div id="2">
  <p>Second</p>
</div>

<div id="3">
  <a href="#" id="open_add">Open add</a>
</div>

<div id="4">
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>

<div id="5">
  <p>Fifth</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move an HTML element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428312/how-do-i-move-an-html-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert div like is this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function( ){
$('div p').click(function() {
$('#add').remove().insertAfter($(this).parent()).show();
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" id="close_add">Close add</a>
</div>
<div id="open_add" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" id="open_add">Open add</a>
</div>

<div id="1">
  <p>First</p>
</div>

<div id="2">
  <p>Second</p>
</div>

<div id="3">
  <p>Third</p>
</div>

<div id="4">
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>

<div id="5">
  <p>Fifth</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But how can make the element chosen be hidden? For ex: clicked on "Fourth" appeared "Close add", and "Fourth" disappeared, etc.

Comment: It is simple. Just hide an element and mark as hidden. At next click show all hidden elements and mark next. Try it, add this code to `click` function


`$('.hiddenItem').removeClass('hiddenItem').show();
$(this).addClass('hiddenItem').hide();`

Comment: Can I ask the last question? Here's an example jsfiddle.net/o3p51bct/2/. How to do to hide the div, so that all the content in it's hidden. And did I write correctly Ajax request for the transfer of id, that in the console is not transferred for some reason.

Comment: 1) To hide parent div just try to hide parent, haha. Like this: replace 
`$(this).addClass('hiddenItem').hide();`
by `$(this).parent().addClass('hiddenItem').hide();`
 
2)To test AJAX request you should be sure, that `some_page.php` in directory exists and it create some response. So, you can google `ajax jquery php` for some examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This completely solved my question.